# Выбрать данные из таблицы, не совпадающее по 1 значению с данными в другой

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго всем времени суток господа (И извиняюсь за вопрос в воскресенье)

```
$zapros = mysql_query("SELECT `field` FROM `table` GROUP BY `field`",$db);
while ($massiv = mysql_fetch_assoc($zapros)) {
    $massiv_arr[] = $massiv["field"];
}
```

Выбираю все уникальные записи из определенной таблицы, с целью добавить их всех в массив. Охота выбрать записи которые != `field2` но в `table2`. т.е. все значения которые в `field2` в `table2` - не должны попасть в результат моего запроса. это сделать как то можно?

скажем у нас маша, петя, вася в первой таблице, во второй петя и вася (в запросе должна остаться только маша), т.е.запрос к первой таблице где `field`!='ни одному значению по определенному полю во второй таблице'

p.s. конечно можно сделать массив с значениями которые мне не надо, потом поменять местами ключи и значения, и проверять что добавлять в массив, но, если есть символы типа решетки, или скобок в массиве - конструкция не работает.

Comment: структуру таблиц можно?

Comment: таблица 1 (art): id, u11, txa. таблица 2 (hid): id, f01, txb. хочу выбрать из таблицы 1 u11, значений которых нет в таблице 2 в поле f01

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT art.u11
FROM art left join hid
on art.u11=hid.f01
```

пробуйте

работающий запрос

```
SELECT art.u11
FROM art
LEFT JOIN hid ON art.u11 = hid.f01
WHERE hid.id IS NULL
```

Comment: попробовал. грубо говоря, если по смыслу:

    $zapros = mysql_query("SELECT `table1`.`field1` FROM `table1` left join `table2` on `table1`.`field` = `table2`.`$field2`",$db);

в массив все же попали значения из `table2`.`$field2`

Comment: все или нет? может они выглядят одитнаково но на самом деле разные?

Comment: все значения, которые я хотел убрать попали в массив. если честно, ответ натолкнул на мыслюь запроса в запросе. думаю в сторону WHERE `field` NOT IN (тут запрос)

Comment: так, вот он ответ (не знаю как, придумал сам, глядя на ответ выше):

$zapros = mysql_query("SELECT `$table1`.`$field1` FROM `$table1` WHERE `$field1` NOT IN (SELECT `$field2` FROM `$table2`) GROUP BY `$field1`",$db) or die("no connect to bd");

Ale_x, спасибо, что хоть как то ответил, а то у меня уже руки опустились когда я решал свою задачу, а так я еще раз подумал

Comment: переписал запрос)

Comment: @mixalef, насчет `NOT IN`  правильно догадались, а вот `GROUP BY` зачем тут нужен?

И еше, когда Вас просят привести описание таблиц, то вместе с именами типы полей надо бы указывать.